# Why I cannot cout a string?

Tags: c++, string, cout

Why I cannot `cout` `string` like this:

```
string text ;
text = WordList[i].substr(0,20) ;
cout << "String is  : " << text << endl ;
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

> Error 2   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  c:\users\mollasadra\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\barnamec\barnamec\barnamec.cpp    67  barnamec**

It is amazing, that even this is not working:

```
string text ;
text = "hello"  ;
cout << "String is  : " << text << endl ;
```

Comment: Can you edit in the error message?

Comment: Did you `#include <iostream>` ?

Comment: not enough info.  what is the error

Comment: I have did that . but again , I have problem .

Comment: Can you post the entire file? We don't know if you're calling this in a function, if you included the right things, etc...

Comment: you are missing includes

Comment: There's nothing "amazing" in this, it's even expected..Did you try my answer?

Comment: Post the entire code, not just a part of it.

Comment: So this was just a compilation error?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You need to include

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: and also `using namespace std` or `using std::cout`; `using std::endl`;

Comment: Yes, but I guess it's included, as there's no error on `string text;` also the edit (added error) says, that this is not the problem but the missing `string` header.

Comment: +1: Many STL headers in Visual C++ (including <iostream>) pull in a definition of the `std::basic_string` class (because they indirectly include the implementation-defined <xstring> header (*never include that directly*)). While that allows you to use the string class, the relevant `operator<<` is defined in the <string> header itself, so you must include that manually. Also relying on other headers to indirectly include the definition of `std::basic_string` works in VC++, but it won't work on all compilers.

Comment: Sven-  Your comment is awesome!  I had a similar problem as this questioner, compiler said operator >> was not defined for types std::cin and std::string.  It turns out I had <iostream> but had forgetten <string>.  I'm used to working on linux w/ gcc which would have complained that std::string is not defined.  Your comment explains perfectly why we instead got the complaint about the operator.  Thanks!!

Comment: @PreetamSingh - uhmmmm, what?

Comment: This works. I missed the #include <string> line in my code. Thanks.

Comment: Order of both #includes is important in some C++ environments (because of conditional compilation)

Answer (score 11):

You need to reference the cout's namespace `std` somehow. For instance, insert

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

on top of your function definition, or the file.

Answer (score 7):

There are several problems with your code:

1. `WordList` is not defined anywhere. You should define it before you use it.
2. You can't just write code outside a function like this. You need to put it in a function.
3. You need to `#include <string>` before you can use the string class and iostream before you use `cout` or `endl`.
4. `string`, `cout` and `endl` live in the `std` namespace, so you can not access them without prefixing them with `std::` unless you use the `using` directive to bring them into scope first.

Comment: none of them worked for me , it seem that problem is with substr

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are good but If you do not want to add string include, you can use the following

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, string& msg)
{
os<<msg.c_str();

return os;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to reference `std::cout` or `std::endl` explicitly.
They are both included in the `namespace std`. `using namespace std` instead of using scope resolution operator `::` every time makes is easier and cleaner.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you may not have noticed but this was addressed in one of the comments of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use c_str() to convert the std::string to const char *.

```
cout << "String is  : " << text.c_str() << endl ;
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using linux system then you need to add

`using namespace std;`

Below headers

If windows then make sure you put headers correctly 
`#include<iostream.h>`

`#include<string.h>`

Refer this it work perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
std::string str="We think in generalities, but we live in details.";
                                       // (quoting Alfred N. Whitehead)

  std::string str2 = str.substr (3,5);     // "think"

   std::size_t pos = str.find("live");      // position of "live" in str

  std::string str3 = str.substr (pos);     
// get from "live" to the end

  std::cout << str2 << ' ' << str3 << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` has nothing to do with the target os being `linux`. Similarly, adding the `.h` to the includes has nothing to do with the target os being windows, `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>` will work on windows.