# C++ Hello World Tutorial Error

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ by following examples in a book and after typing this out and double checking I keep getting error messages. I cant figure out what is wrong. I'm using Visual C++ 2010 if it matters.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Prompt the user for data 
cout << "Please enter two words:" << endl;

//Read in the values
string b, c;
cin >> b >> c;

// Give feedback
cout << "I understood: "
     << b << ", and "
     << c << endl;

// NOw, lets's read a whole line of text as a single entity
cout << "Now, type in a whole line of text, "
     << "with as many blanks as you want:"
     << endl;

//getline() is a function; we'll talk more about them in Part3 
string wholeLine;
getline( cin, wholeLine );

//In the cout statement below, remember that \"
// is an escape sequence!
cout << "I understood: \"" << wholeLine << "\"" << endl;

// And we're done! 
return 0;
}
```

There are four errors.
The error codes are:

**Error 1** error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  i:\helloworld.cpp   11

**Error 2** error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  i:\helloworld.cpp   15

**Error 3** error C3861: 'getline': identifier not found    i:\helloworld.cpp   25

**Error 4** error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  i:\helloworld.cpp   29

Comment: Have you included `stdafx.h`?

Comment: My best guess is you have to include stdio.h or stdafx.h or something, too.  Obviously something isn't getting included in iostream that it's expecting.

Comment: `#include <string>` is definitely required. Without it, you don't have the correct declaration of `getline()`.

Comment: Not just `getline()`, you also can't use the `string` class without including `string` header.

Comment: so should ... using namespace std; be using namespace stdafx.h

Comment: No, `#include <string>`. I don't think `#include <stdafx.h>` is required, but I could be wrong (not a MSVC user). Get rid of `using namespace std;`, is my recommendation.

Comment: What is the `stdafx.h` header for, guys? I have never used it any program. Has it got to do something with Visual Studio?

Comment: `stdafx.h` has to do with precomiled headers in Microsoft Visual C++, as I understand. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdafx.h#stdafx.h

Comment: possible duplicate of [why I can not cout a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320995/why-i-can-not-cout-a-string)

Comment: @user3280763 Just try including `#include <string>` at the top and see if it works.

Comment: You don't need (or even want, when learning C++) `stdafx.h`.  It's really only for pre-compiled headers.

Answer (score 7):

Missing `#include <string>` for `string`.

Comment: This is it. `<string>` defines its operators `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I followed the book word for word and it doesn't show this. I think I better find a new book to use.

Comment: @user3280763 what is the book?

Comment: Learn C++ By Making Games by Yuzmwa/Laramee (ISBN:1-58450-455-2) The sad part is this is only chapter 3.

Comment: @user3280763: Have a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I'll bet it still doesn't work (or there's some additional code you haven't shown).

Comment: @user3280763 That book list is great but can be a bit overwhelming! I, personally, suggest "C++ primer plus(6th ed) by Stephen Prata". Have a look at it.

Comment: @Jatin I would highly recommend Stroustrup's book _Programming: Principles and Practice using C++_.

Comment: thanks for all the book suggestions, I'll definitely look into them. @ James Kanze: that's all the code and it works without error but it doesn't allow me to type in the string. I'll mess with it some more before calling it quits and getting a new book.

Comment: @JamesKanze I haven't read it! Although, my experience with books by authors of languages hasn't been the best! I mean, K&R comes highly recommended for C, but I didn't find it suitable for very beginners!

Comment: @Jatin K&R (and the earlier Stroustrup) are excellent books, but they don't target beginners.  _Programming: Principles and Practice using C++_ does; it was designed for people who know nothing about programming, and how to write programs, and it addresses those issues more than just pure C++.

Answer (score 1):

As Wesley already said, ensure you have the  library  included.

Also, be very careful when using *getline()* and *cin* in the same program. One can affect the other and you can get unexpected results. To be safe, I've found that it is useful to use *cin.ignore()* after using a *cin* and *before* using a getline. Cheers!