# What am I doing wrong, it's very basic C++ but gives an error?

Tags: c++, substr

[the code i wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1lpW.png)

What am i doing wrong in here it gives me an error and its very very basic.

```
enter code here

# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string firstone = "giraffe academy";
    cout << firstone.substr(8, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please always include the exact error, as text. No images of code or errors.

Comment: You have forgotten to `#include <string>`. Some compilers don't mind, but don't rely on that.

Comment: missing `#include <string>` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I cannot cout a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320995/why-i-cannot-cout-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

You need to

```
# include <string>
```

that defines `<<` for `std::string`

Comment: in the video, I watched guy did it without using include <string> part. Can that be because of the compilers we use?

Comment: @elf not so much a compiler as the `std` library; see the link posted in the comments for details.